# Code coverage statistics data is empty and coverage badge is unknown

Tags: gitlab-ci, code-coverage

I'm using Jacoco for code coverage and visualizing it, visualizing is working well but Code coverage statistics data is empty and the coverage badge is unknown.
The gitlab-ci file for the test is :

```
test-ut:
stage: test
image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
script:
   - mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent -Dgroups="unit-test" test jacoco:report
artifacts:
paths:
  - target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml
  - target/site/jacoco/index.html
coverage: '/Total.*?([0-9]{1,3})%/'
```

Coverage report :
[Coverage report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9J4v.png)

Code coverage statistics
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC5Tq.png)

Comment: Actually, I found this :

https://cylab.be/blog/94/compute-the-code-coverage-of-your-tests-with-java-and-maven
and my problem solved.